# How to make movable slideshow at the start of android application?

Tags: java, android, slideshow

First of all I apologise for my English, because I am maybe not specific enough. I would like to make a slideshow at the start of android application. For example you can see the android application of linkedIN. I don´t want it to move on its own. I want user to move it. There will be e.g. three pictures with text fields and buttons and user will be able to move them right or left. Is there any tutorial how to make this probably easy thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use VIewPager for this.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewFlipper widget provided with Android SDK as follows:

Step1:Add ViewFlipper element into you activity layout xml.Inside ViewFlipper element add Three ImageView elements 
Step2: Use either buttons[Next or Prev.] to navigate across images
Step3: Use Proper Events to detect swipe

For details refer link:
http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewPagerIndicator Library by Jake Wharton

Source: [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)

A complete example of implementing ViewPagerIndicator is available here & might be useful,

[Android Jake Wharton ViewPager Indicator Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jake-wharton-viewpager-indicator-tutorial/)